# selector with hinttext color in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml, android-selector

Basically, I want to change the color of hint when the EditText property `focusable` and `foucsableInTouchMode` is set to false.

It's all good with `textColor` but got useless with `textColorHint` property of Editext.

I tried my best effort but all in vein, so my code is as follows

I have create a drawable called "colorListfile" stated as follows,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/login_signup_header_textcolor" />

    <item
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

</selector>
```

My EditText is shown below,

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="zuluzulu01"
    android:textColorHint="@drawable/colorListfile"
    android:hint="Name" />
```

But this or any other approach didn't work. But this all code work fine when this property is set to `textColor`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can change the `color` to `drawable`, such like `<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/login_signup_header_textcolor" />`

Comment: @周恩旭, thanks buddy , but that too doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You said you want

> to change the color of hint when the EditText property focusable and focusableInTouchMode is set to false

Your `ColorStateList` works perfectly. It's only that it depends on `state_focused` (i.e. the `View` has focus) and  `state_window_focused` (i.e. the window of the `View` has focus).

To make sure, I've just tested with two `EditText`s (so the `EditText` can lose focus while the user is busy in the same window), a `Button` (to en-/disable the `EditText`) and an emulator running Nougat (so I can switch the focus to another window)

Unfortunately, there are no selector item attributes *state_focusable* and *state_focusableInTouchMode*.(See the documentation for [Color List Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html))
So if you really want the hint color to depend on `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` being set to false, you will have to set the desired color programmatically every time you toggle these attributes.

```
myEditText.setHintTextColor(Color.GREEN)
```